# Highlight a particulatr position in List View

Tags: java, android, date, android-listview, baseadapter

Sorry if the question seems to  long than normal or difficult to understand .In my task I have to show an **listview** which will display a date and title as string values.I am using **Arraylist** which uses a model class for passing the data to adapter.

```
vaccinationScheduleAdapter=new VaccinationScheduleAdapter(mActivity,DateOfBirth,VaccShdleModelArrayList);
        lstMenus.setAdapter(vaccinationScheduleAdapter);
```

Where DateOfBirth is a DateValue,which can be changed.The value for `VaccShdleModelArrayList` is passed through a model class

```
public String getmDescription() {
    return mDescription;
}
public String getmNumberOfMonths() {
    return mNumberOfMonths;
}
```

The date showing in listview will calculated using the passed value DateOfBirth and mNumberOfMonths.the calculation will perform in Custom Adapter class

```
NumberOfMonths = Integer.parseInt(atrNumberOfMonths);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(DateOfBirth);
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, NumberOfMonths);
```

For example the `getmNumberOfMonths` will return 1`,3,5,7,..` then it will added to month of passed `DateOfBirth`.if i passed `01/08/2015` the result after calculation will be `01/09/2015,01/10/2015,01/12/2015,01/03/2015...`
I want highlight the next future date if it is not containing current date. 
I managed to find the position needed to be highlight by sorting dates coming after current date, but the problem is sorting and finding of happens only when the position of the adapter will be last. please help me to do this. stuck in this problem for a long time.

Here is the Adapter Class,

```
    public class VaccinationScheduleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<VaccinationScheduleModel> mListItems;
    private Activity mActivity;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Integer[] mListIcons;
    private Date DateOfBirth;
    private int NumberOfMonths;
    private ArrayList<VaccinationScheduleAppoinmentModel> SottList = new ArrayList<>();
    VaccinationScheduleAppoinmentModel ap;
    CalenderModel calModel = new CalenderModel();
    private int maxarraySize;
    public static int nextvalue;

    public VaccinationScheduleAdapter(Activity mActivity, Date DateOfBirth, ArrayList<VaccinationScheduleModel> mListItems) {
//        super();
        this.maxarraySize = mListItems.size();
        this.mActivity = mActivity;
        this.mListItems = mListItems;
        this.DateOfBirth = DateOfBirth;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity.getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mListItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mListItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_lv_vacc_schedule,
                    parent, false);
        } else {
            convertView = convertView;
        }

        String atrNumberOfMonths = mListItems.get(position).getmNumberOfMonths();
        NumberOfMonths = Integer.parseInt(atrNumberOfMonths);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(DateOfBirth);
        cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, NumberOfMonths);
        Date result = cal.getTime();

        String dayOfTheWeek = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("EEEE", result);//Thursday
        String stringMonth = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MMM", result); //Jun
        String intMonth = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("MM", result); //06
        String year = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy", result); //2013
        String day = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd", result); //20
        // System.out.println("19102015:VaccinationScheduleAdapter" + result);
        TextView txtVaccTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtVaccTitle);
        TextView txtVaccMonth = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtVaccMonth);
        TextView txtVaccDay = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtVaccDay);
        TextView txtVaccYear = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtVaccYear);
        RelativeLayout relrow = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.relrow);
        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        imgIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.calendar_icon);
        txtVaccTitle.setText(mListItems.get(position).getmDescription());
        txtVaccMonth.setText(stringMonth);
        txtVaccDay.setText(day);
        txtVaccYear.setText(year);
        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        int comresult = cal.compareTo(cal2);

        System.out.println("27102015 cal1 Added date:"+cal);
        System.out.println("27102015 cal1 Current date:"+cal2);
//        System.out.println("22102015:maxarraySize" + maxarraySize);
//        System.out.println("22102015:position" + position);
        System.out.println("22102015:comresult"+comresult);

        if (position == (maxarraySize - 1)) {

            Collections.sort(SottList, new ScheduleDateComp());
            System.out.println("Sorted list entries: ");
            for (VaccinationScheduleAppoinmentModel e : SottList) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            if (SottList.size() != 0) {
                int aortlistposition = SottList.get(0).getposition();
                System.out.println("26102015:highlight position" + aortlistposition);
                System.out.println("26102015:current position" + position);
                nextvalue = aortlistposition;
                if (position == aortlistposition) {
                    relrow.setBackgroundResource(R.color.listview_blueback);
                }
            } else {

            }
        }
        //  System.out.println("comresult" + comresult);
        if (isSameDay(cal, cal2)) {
//            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
//            calModel.mCaldate = cal;
//            calModel.mPosition = position;
            System.out.println("isSameDay");
//            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selector_highlight);
//            txtVaccTitle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
//            txtVaccDay.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
//            txtVaccMonth.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
//            txtVaccYear.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        else if (comresult < 0) {

            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            txtVaccTitle.setTextColor(mActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.listview_textcolor));
            txtVaccDay.setTextColor(mActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.listview_textcolor));
            txtVaccMonth.setTextColor(mActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.listview_textcolor));
            txtVaccYear.setTextColor(mActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.listview_textcolor));
//            txtVaccTitle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
//            txtVaccDay.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
//            txtVaccMonth.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
//            txtVaccYear.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);


        }
       else {
            if ((comresult > 0)) {
                ap = new VaccinationScheduleAppoinmentModel(result, position);
                SottList.add(ap);
                // convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selector_highlight);

                Collections.sort(SottList, new ScheduleDateComp());


                if ((position == SottList.get(0).getposition()) ) {//&& !isSameDay(cal, cal2)

                    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_selector_highlight);
                    txtVaccTitle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    txtVaccDay.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    txtVaccMonth.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    txtVaccYear.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                } else {
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    txtVaccTitle.setTextColor(mActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.listview_textcolor));
                    txtVaccDay.setTextColor(mActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.listview_textcolor));
                    txtVaccMonth.setTextColor(mActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.listview_textcolor));
                    txtVaccYear.setTextColor(mActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.listview_textcolor));

                }
                //  checkNextDay();

            }
        }


        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }


    public int nextday() {
        return nextvalue;
    }

    public boolean isSameDay(Calendar cal1, Calendar cal2) {
        if (cal1 == null || cal2 == null)
            return false;
        return (cal1.get(Calendar.ERA) == cal2.get(Calendar.ERA)
                && cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR)
                && cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
    }


    class ScheduleDateComp implements Comparator<VaccinationScheduleAppoinmentModel> {


        @Override
        public int compare(VaccinationScheduleAppoinmentModel ap1, VaccinationScheduleAppoinmentModel ap2) {
            if ((ap1.getDate()).after((ap2.getDate())))

            {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would be very thankful if any one can be help me. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

For highlighting a list position You need to set `listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);`
then `listview.setSelection(int position);`

Comment: I have this         lstMenus.setSelection(vaccinationScheduleAdapter.nextday());
But what to do after this?

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a array of future date positions after sorting VaccinationScheduleAppoinmentModel implement the compareto(). You can look at this link to know how [[Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property][1]).  apply your sorting logic and mainatain an  array of future date positions from this sorted list.  You can set listview choice mode as multiple, and set selected state for positions that you require.

Answer (score 0):

as Akhil mentioned,

```
listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE); then      
listview.setSelection(int position);
```

after you do this, you need to set the item which you want to highted itemView.setSelected(true), I belive the will be a variable to judge if the item will be highted.
if it still not workaround, consider if the background of your item view is correct with selector file.